# Scoping AWS S3 objects to Rails Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a rails app setup with Devise, AWS S3 and Highcharts.

Currently the users can log in and upload text files to S3. Rails then requests the data directly from AWS and passes it to Highcharts for processing – spitting out a nice and pretty graph. However, users can currently see every piece of data that's been uploaded.

I’m not sure how to setup a relationship between users and their respective uploaded objects. What is the best way to ‘scope’ data within S3 so users can only see the data that they have uploaded? I am assuming this is done through an AWS ACL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The S3 bucket ACLs are designed to control bucket access to AWS accounts and anonymous requests as a whole, as documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAuthAccess.html). As such, I don't think the ACLs will work for your use case.

A better solution could be [IAM policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingIAMPolicies.html). The idea, here, would be to create a new IAM user for every account registered in your app. This can be done both easily and programmatically. Then, fracture your bucket's namespace along some line, perhaps account_id:

```
s3://mybucket/account1/
s3://mybucket/account2/
s3://mybucket/account3/
...
```

On account creation, construct an IAM policy that grants RW access to *just* that account's folder.

I haven't actually tried this for your use case, but I'm fairly confident it'd work. IAM also comes at no cost and its API is trivially easy to use once you figure out how amazon resources are named. More details are [in the API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html).

Comment: S3 is a flat file structure, so is it possible to programmatically fracture the namespace as you've mentioned?

Comment: Sure. It's technically flat but the IAM permissions behave as if its not, and most things that interact with S3 treat the namespace prefixes as folders. Check out [this discussion](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=66764) for some working examples of IAM policies.